# How can I detect if app is running on PDA

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to detect if my app is running on a PDA (with android OS) or a conventional smartphone?

Comment: What is that for?

Comment: Need to write special code if the app is running on PDA since that device has a different configuration (Not having PlayStore is an example)

Comment: First what *really* is PDA here? Also it sounds it is irrelevant what device it is. What sounds relevant is "configuration" (whatever it is). Why can't you just check if said configuration is a needed and act if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between a PDA and a traditional smartphone, except for *possibly* the presence of a cellular radio (and even that's not assured, there may be one).  THere's also no difference between a tablet and a smartphone.  They're marketing terms, not actual differences between devices.  Take any smartphone and smack on an assistant looking UI and you have a PDA.

BTW, not all Android phones have the play store either-  its common in Asia for low price brands to not pay Google for it and just load a version of AOSP on it.

So if you want actual help, you need to describe what's different about this device that matters to your program, and then we might be able to help you find workarounds.  But there's no way to tell "PDA" because "PDA" has no meaning.